# How can I JOIN or Attach multiple SQLite DBs using ServiceStack OrmLite?

Tags: c#, sqlite, ormlite-servicestack

The excellent [**ServiceStack OrmLite**](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite) has a ton of features.

I have a scenario where I have two or more separate SQLite DBs, how can I join/attach them using OrmLite?

Do I have to write RAW SQL or are there any built-in features I can use?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OrmLite supports [Multi-nested named connections](https://docs.servicestack.net/ormlite/multi-database-connections) which lets you register multiple RDBMS connections under different names, e.g:

```
//Set default connection
var dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(
    "~/App_Data/db.sqlite".MapAbsolutePath(), SqliteDialect.Provider);

//Setup multiple named connections
dbFactory.RegisterConnection("db1", 
    "~/App_Data/db1.sqlite".MapAbsolutePath(), SqliteDialect.Provider);

dbFactory.RegisterConnection("db2", 
    "~/App_Data/db2.sqlite".MapAbsolutePath(), SqliteDialect.Provider);
```

You can then access each Sqlite db with the registered name.

As Sqlite doesn't support cross-database joins, you can't create a SQL query that spans multiple DB's, so if you want to merge results from both you'd need to do it in code, e.g:

```
var results = new List<Table>();
using (var db1 = dbFactory.OpenDbConnection("db1"))
using (var db2 = dbFactory.OpenDbConnection("db2"))
{
    results.AddRange(db1.Select<Table>(q => q.Category = category));
    results.AddRange(db2.Select<Table>(q => q.Category = category));
}
```

Comment: mythz, thanks for the answer. On a separate note, having looked at the source code, "OrmLiteDialectProviderBase.cs" declares 2 loggers, one is protected Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(IOrmLiteDialectProvider)); the other a couple of lines below is: private log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(OrmLiteDialectProviderBase<>)); is that intentional?

Comment: @MaYaN yeah that was a mistake [fixed in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/80910c8ca0bf1ec12ed51da6ab1d52437f2eb353) - thx for reporting :)

Comment: @mythz how would you implement a single transaction spanning the two databases?